# Finding Null Records - PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I’m trying to get all the records from table a that are not found in table b… I’m getting zero results, and I know that is not the case...Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
proc sql;
title 'Merge';
select a.report_date, a.pharmacy, a.pme_id, a.rx_number, a.product, a.status, a.fill
from hc.horizoncaresMaster a 
left join  TMP1.horizoncares_master b on a.rx_number = b.rx_number
where( a.report_date in ('2016-11-11','2016-11-04')
and a.status ="Hold"
and a.pme_id=62
and b.rx_number is NULL )
order by a.report_date;
quit;
```

Comment: The query looks ok, so even you say are sure there is data. Change to `SELECT *` and reduce the `WHERE` filter to few field to make sure

Comment: That didn't work either, the error I keep getting is NO ROWS WERE SELECTED if that helps..

Comment: That doesnt make sense. Your remove the where are no rows?

Comment: What if you change "and b.rx_number is NULL " to "and b.rx_number is missing "?

Comment: tried that, same says No ROWS Selected...but I can query off the tables individually...

Comment: @SQUISH If possible provide some data from each tables.

Comment: ok, you meant in my select statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
select your_var_list from a where rx_number is not in (select rx_number from b)
```